# How to handle the parameters which have the same name as field names?

Tags: c++

For example, if my parameter name in some method using x, y
 my field also contains x and y

I am using

```
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
```

Is this recommended?

Comment: Yes. Using `this` is the only way to differentiate.

Comment: Unless in constructor where `Foo::Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}` works.

Comment: One of the convention is to use _x instead of x as parameter name.

Comment: As with most things like this, it's personal preference. I'd say it's fine in setter methods and constructors but would probably prefer to avoid it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but generally you want to make your member variables look separate from the parameter variables. When I was in school, they taught us to use m_x and m_y (for member_x and member_y) rather than just x and y.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any difference, since you specify that you are assigning the value of local variable `x` to the object variable `this->x`.

I don't there is any specification that says it is not recommended but as a generally practice to avoid confusion you should use non-similar names.